# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/NetworkConnector

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

I have seen some similar question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28170244/jetty-throws-noclassdeffounderror-org-eclipse-jetty-util-futurecallback-on-shut), but unfortunately none of them helped me to figure out my issue. When i boot my spring mvc application i face with the following errors:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enable debug logging (start with --debug)


[2m2016-09-05 11:30:14.257[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m81080[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application startup failed

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/NetworkConnector
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.start(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:129) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at com.example.ClientManagmentSystemApplication.main(ClientManagmentSystemApplication.java:14) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.NetworkConnector
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

and here is my **pom.xml** file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>               
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-all</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.16.v20140903</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I tried to remove the devtool, but it still complains with the same errors.
what can i do?

Comment: Well, do you have the class `org.eclipse.jetty.server.NetworkConnector` in your classpath? It is in the [`jetty-server` Maven dependency](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server/9.2.1.v20140609/org/eclipse/jetty/server/NetworkConnector.java). Can you post the result of `mvn dependency:tree`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer. I don't know how does it happen, but the 8080 port was busy.
When i open it with the commands:

```
netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:8080
taskkill -F -PID 3116
```

It works well.

Comment: I got something similar: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/http/pathmap/MappedResource`, caused by the same problem.